# PineScript: Strategy Close

Tags: pine-script

I am coding a strategy and trying to close all open positions at 15:15 intraday

```
timessession2 = input("1510-1515", type=input.session,title="Closing Trading Session")
time_cond1 = not na(times1)
strategy.close_all(time_cond1)
```

It isnt doing anything
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
timessession2 = input("1510-1515", type=input.session,title="Closing Trading Session")
time_cond1 = not na(time(timeframe.period, timessession2))
strategy.close_all(time_cond1)
```

Comment: Sorry...no change